# Rails 3.2.8 - How do I do recursive has_one check?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following model:

```
class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
 ...

 has_one :next_point, class_name: "Point", foreign_key: "next_point_id"
 belongs_to :previous_point, class_name: "Point", foreign_key: "next_point_id"

 # It should return an array with the next remaining points
 def next_remaining_points
 end

end
```

How do I do a method that returns the next_point until the next_point is nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple recursive solution to this in your Ruby code, but be warned that this can execute a DB query for each call.  You may be better off with a custom SQL query.

```
class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def last_point  # Or some better name
    next_point.try(:last_point) || self
  end
```